# Assigning column names in R with another dataset

Tags: r

I'm trying to read in two data files, one is the actual data, the other is a file of column names in rows. I then need to assign the column names to the actual data. Below is what I have but its not assigning them properly.

```
#read in the data
glass_data = read.csv('/all_datasets/glass/glass.txt', header=FALSE)
glass_headers = read.csv('/all_datasets/glass/header.txt')

#add the names
names(glass_data) = c(glass_headers)
```

Comment: Sounds like `glass_headers` is the wrong length or class to be the colnames of your data frame. It shoud be a character vector of the same length as your data frame is wide.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
colnames(glass_data) <- glass_headers[, 1]
```

Comment: hmmm that gives me the following error:

Error in names(x) <- value: 'names' attribute [18] must be the same length as the vector [11]
Traceback:

1. `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 . 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
 . " as "), class = "factor"))

Comment: Hard to tell without a sample of the data to be honest. It sounds like you may not have exactly the right number of column names in glass_headers. Try length(colnames(glass_data)) and length(glass_headers[, 1]) to check